# Como colocar um coluna ReadOnly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

Estou tentando deixar apenas uma coluna do `GridView` como `ReadOnly`, estou fazendo assim:

```
        if (id_crm == 0)
        {
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(cod_crm());

            DataTable dat_itens = new DataTable();

            dat_itens.Columns.Add("ITEM", typeof(int));
            dat_itens.Columns.Add("DESCRIÇÃO", typeof(string));
            dat_itens.Columns.Add("DESCRIÇÃO NF", typeof(string));
            dat_itens.Columns.Add("QUANTIDADE", typeof(int));
            dat_itens.Columns.Add("OF ORIGEM", typeof(string));

            gridControl1.DataSource = dat_itens;

            gridView5.Columns[0].Width = 28;
            gridView5.Columns[0].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
            gridView5.Columns["ITEM"].ReadOnly = true;  

        }
```

Porém, ele exibe um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade [GridColumn.ReadOnly](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumntopic) é só de leitura.

Para indicar se uma coluna é "editável" ou não tem de o fazer via propriedade [GridColumn.OptionsColumn](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_OptionsColumntopic) assim:

```
gridView5.Columns["ITEM"].OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: muito obrigado. funcionou perfeitamente, pode me dar uma breve explicação sobre oque seria uma propriedade só de leitura? Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Uma propriedade só de leitura não pode ser alterada, só é possível obter o seu valor. Ela é declarada da seguinte forma `public tipo Nome {get;}`

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que isso só se aplica aos GridView's da DevExpress.

Comment: @jbueno Sim, a pergunta refere-se às GridView's da DevExpress.